# Trigger jQuery click event with url parameter?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery click function on my page which triggers the opening of a feedback form div. Basically I want to specify a url that will trigger this event without it needing to be clicked. Such as foo.com?formopen

Is this possible? I'm thinking I need to pass some data through the url but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a hash in your URL like:

```
foo.com#formopen
```

Then find that hash on load like:

```
$(function(){

   if (window.location.hash){
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
      if (hash == "formopen"){
         openFeedbackForm();
      }
   }

});
```

---

**DEMO:**

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/J5cxc/

Demo Without Hash: http://fiddle.jshell.net/J5cxc/show (no alert)

Demo With Hash: http://fiddle.jshell.net/J5cxc/show/#foobar (alert called)

Comment: this answer solved a tricky UI challenge for me and deserves many more upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Hey there are many ways to do this.

Method One - Using Query String params

In your url pass in a query string value which indicates that the form should be opened.

So your url would be

```
www.foo.com?feedback=true
```

Then in JS you can do:

```
var params = {};
var ps = window.location.search.split(/\?|&/);
for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    if (ps[i]) {
        var p = ps[i].split(/=/);
        params[p[0]] = p[1];
    }
}
if(params.feedback){
     $(".feedback-div").show();
}
```

Method Two - Using a hash-tag in the url

Your url will be like:

```
www.foo.com#feedback
```

In your JS:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#feedback") > -1) {
     $(".feedback-div").show();
}
```